# Is there an easy way to draw lines with measurements like in SketchUp?

Tags: modeling

In SketchUp, I click the line tool, then click on the stage and move the mouse in the desired direction followed by just typing in a number and clicking enter.

I wanna be able to do the same in Blender. Is there a way to do this? Sorry if this is a super low-level question. Even if I have to add plugins or something can I get Blender to work like SketchUp?

I wanna switch over to Blender as I'm starting to model cities with photo mapped terrains and SketchUp can't deal with the data very well. Also, I'd love to be part of this community and help others in an open-source program.

Comment: You could always add a plane, and type in the dimensions.  Then delete afterwards.
Not the exact solution, but something that would function.
Or there is a "measurement" tool in layout mode and modeling mode, on the left tool bar.  But that doesn't quite sound like what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Mike. I tried that but it isn't as quick as just drawing lines. Any other ideas? I'm basically looking for something like Inkscape, Illustrator or SketchUp.

Comment: Sorry, very new to blender, and never touched those other programs.

Comment: I just wanna draw lines and type in the distances as I go.

Comment: Even if there are plugins, I'm happy to load extra bits to be able to draw lines properly.